# CSS keyframes ignored/not taken into account

Tags: html, css

I use this animation in CSS as a mixin (in LESS).
So the animation works because apparently, it takes into account the first part, but not the @keyframes stuff. If I remove the @keyframes, it doesn't change anything to the animation.
But the problem is I need to apply @keyframes parameters because else, in chromium it's blurred and there is a fix (-webkit-filter(0)) but it seems like it's not working because keyframes arenot taken into account.

```
.VANISHIN {


 -webkit-animation-name: vanishIn;
  animation-name: vanishIn;

    animation-duration: 0.5s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;

    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes vanishIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2, 2);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes vanishIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: scale(2, 2);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify more on what you mean by *If I remove the @keyframes, it doesn't change anything to the animation*? It is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry for the time.
It means if I completely erase that part from the css, it still works the same way. It means it does nothing. If I modify settings in the @keyframes it doesn't change anything anyway.

Comment: .VANISHIN {


 -webkit-animation-name: vanishIn;
  animation-name: vanishIn;

    animation-duration: 0.5s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;

    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

works the same with or without keyframes

Comment: Keyframes are mandatory for animations to work and so there are only two possibilities - (a) The keyframes are defined somewhere else in your code (say a library or an external CSS file etc) or (b) Your animation is not at all working. Create a demo and it would be easier to debug.